# How to remove empty spaces in the columns using HTML5, CSS3

Tags: html, css

[image]   There are multiple columns in which the data would be fetched dynamically. So the column which have more data would take the complete height. The other columns in the same row, would also consume the maximum height (even though they don't have much data) So, there would be empty space left.How do i remove this empty space.

```
 <td style="text-align: center;height:100%;">
 <table style="border-collapse:collapse; margin: -6px -14px -7px -11px; 
width:100%;height:100%;>
<tr>
    <td style="height:100%;" >
        <table  style="width:100%;height:100%" ><tr > 
            <td height="100%" ng-repeat="--">
                -- multiple div and span blocks used to loop multiple times- 
        </td></tr></table>
```

Comment: add a working code

Comment: but isn't that how tables work? Columns in rows are of equal height? How would `remove empty space` work?

Comment: Could you show an example of current display and if possible expected one to confirm? I fear what you ask is against the very purpose of `table`

Comment: What is your task manager of module bundler, gulp, grunt, webpack, parcel, which one?

Comment: @Kaddath : Please find the attached image.

Comment: so, do you want that the vertical separator in the right cell (between the green checks and red crosses) take the whole cell height? Or that the cell itself shrinks so that its height is smaller? The second one is not possible/proper solution with a `table` (and just for info, using a table to set a page general display structure is not recommended, both for flexibility and performance)

Comment: @Kaddath : I actually wanted the second one. But since it's not possible as you suggested, want to know if it's possible to increase the verticle border's height to the whole cell height.

Comment: To be able to answer that, i would need and example of the HTML inside a cell, and the styles that go with it

Answer (score 0):

the only way i know to have "not aligned" cell separations in a table is to use `colspan` and `rowspan`, but these functionalities can only fuse cells together, not create an isolated cell (isolated in the sense that it would have it's own dimensioning despite the row or column it corresponds).

If in theory your layout could be possible with a `table`, it would involve a lot of code to have these cell fusions OK and probably need javascript for the dimensioning.

example with rowspan:

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">B</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td><td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**In conclusion**, your layout would be much more easily done with `div` and eventually wrapper divs if you want to emulate rows or columns. This will also be quicker to render, `table` is nowadays considered a bad choice to organize a layout.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. But, however my question is not regarding rowspan or colspan. I have multiple tables inside table. And i have applied border to the 3rd table inside a table. So i want to increase this border size, such that it touches the outside table.